# How to change the MAC adress of FPGA ZedBoard

Tags: fpga, mac-address, zynq, petalinux

How can I assign different MAC addresses to the FPGA? Currently all the ZedBoards have the same default MAC addresses.

I'm using PetaLinux and my FPGA ZedBoards boot from SD card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the MAC address using petalinux-config:

`petalinux-config --> Subsystem AUTO Hardware Settings --> Ethernet Settings --> Ethernet MAC address`

You can also change it from the device tree:

```
&gem0 {
        ... <other settings> ...
        local-mac-address = [00 0a 35 00 00 00];
        ... <more settings> ...
};
```